# Previous indra's scripturical evidence?

Tags: indra

As we all know indra is not a name rather a title 
Sources : -http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a020.htm , 
.So are there any scriptures describing next birth of previous indra's??.Like many puranas give ideas about previous birth's of an individual.

Comment: Indra is NOT necessarily the name of a post.Indra is a name of Para-Brahman in the Vedas. In the Puranas, Indra became the post of the king of heaven. In Devi- Mahatmya, Mahisasura became Indra and was later killed by Mother Mahalakshmi

Comment: @Partha we know almost nothing about vedas and their translation as 1 in billions can understanding it.And their are many indras mentioned in mahabharata.

Comment: indro mayaavih puru-rupa iyate--here indra means Brahman according to Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath

Comment: @ yaa Partha i agree.But i also consider the fact that understanding the real meaning written in scriptures are very difficult and one knows it is not the common one.